# Why is my array of objects of type File undefined when I put formData in a object with other properties and post it to the server?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, post, file-upload

I am able to upload files to the server with the following code:

service.component.ts

```
  uploadFiles(){
    console.log("uploadFiles() in Service");
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      for(let i = 0; i<this.files_to_upload.length; i++){
      formData.append('files', this.files_to_upload.item(i));
  }

       return this.http.post(`${this.basicUrl}/post/file`, formData).subscribe(
         res => console.log(res)
       )
      
  }
```

In Express:

```
app.post('/post/file', (req,res)=>{
    console.log("post/file");
    console.log(req.body.files)
    if(req.files){
        console.log(req.files);
        let files = req.files.files;
        if(files.length > 1){
        for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        let filename = files[i].name
        files[i].mv(__dirname + '/uploads/' + filename, function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Uploaded")
            } 
        })
    }   
  }
}
```

This would work perfectly.

But now I want to extend the function in my service so that I have a path I can navigate to and upload those files in the correct folder.

```
uploadFiles(path){
    console.log("uploadFiles() in Service");
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      for(let i = 0; i<this.files_to_upload.length; i++){
      formData.append('files', this.files_to_upload.item(i));
  }

       return this.http.post(`${this.basicUrl}/post/file`, {files: formData, path: path}).subscribe(
         res => console.log(res)
       )
      
  }
```

But then somehow I cannot acces the files.
If I do the follwing in Express:

```
app.post('/post/file', (req,res)=>{
    console.log("post/file");
    console.log(req.body) 
    ...
```

The body has both properties `files` and `path` but `files` is an empty object...
How can I access the files when extending the object sending to the server?

Comment: I solved it. I just append a new object ```path``` to my formData and I can access it by using following code: ```req.body.path```, if someone wonders. To access the files you have to use this code ```req.files```. I do not know why they are in different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a file, the body should be encoded using `multipart/form-data` method. 
 You are sending a `Json` object (although it has a multipart property) therefore the body would be encoded using `application/json` method which is the reason why you can't access the uploaded files.